# Alterar menu dropdown atravez do input checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou tentando criar um menu dropdown dinâmico que possa mostrar seu conteúdo conforme checkbox seja marcado.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkb" value="produto"/>Produto</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkb" value="servico"/>Servicos</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkb" value="outros"/>Outros</label><br/>
</div>

<select name="listaPSO" id="LISTAPSO">
<option value="">--- Select ---</option>
<option value="">----Produto----</option>
<option value="Produto">Celular</option>
<option value="Produto">Tablet</option>
<option value="Produto">TV</option>
<option value="">----Servico----</option>
<option value="Servico">Troca</option>
<option value="Servico">Compra</option>
<option value="">----Outros----</option>
<option value="Outros">Outros A</option>
<option value="Outros">Outros B</option>
</select>
```

Conforme eu marco checkbox, gostaria de poder mostrar no menu dropdown apenas o conteúdo relacionado,quando marco Produto teria que mostrar apenas a lista de produtos no menu, assim como serviço e outros, não sei se essa forma que estou fazendo é ideal, o problema que estou tendo é que ao marcar e desmarcar o conteúdo nem sempre marca corretamente e ao desmarcar todos ele fica com última lista marca.

```
<script>
$('#checkb').change(function () {
var coffee = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkb"]:checked');
var x = document.getElementById('listaPSO');
var options = x.getElementsByTagName('option');

for (i = 0; i < coffee.length; i++) {   //Pega os valores checkbox
 if (coffee[i].checked) {
  if (coffee[i].value == 'produto') { 
   $("#productList").children('option[value="produto"]').show();
   $("#productList").children('option[value="servico"]').hide();
   $("#productList").children('option[value="outros"]').hide();
  }
   if (coffee[i].value == 'servico') { 
    $("#productList").children('option[value="produto"]').hide();
    $("#productList").children('option[value="servico"]').show();
    $("#productList").children('option[value="outros"]').hide();
  }
   if (coffee[i].value == 'outros') {  
    $("#productList").children('option[value="produto"]').hide();
    $("#productList").children('option[value="servico"]').hide();
    $("#productList").children('option[value="Non"]').show();
    } else { 
     $("#productList").children('option[value="produto"]').show();
     $("#productList").children('option[value="servico"]').show();
     $("#productList").children('option[value="outros"]').show();
    }
   } 
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Podes mudar esse HTML ou não tens acesso a ele?

Comment: Não vejo problema em alterar o HTML, o que estou buscando é uma solução usando checkbox e dropbox.

Answer (score 2):

Se podes mudar o HTML podemos juntar mais informação a essas `option` que facilita a tarefa.

```js
$('#checkbox').change(function() {
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
  var options = document.querySelectorAll('#LISTAPSO option');

  var filtros = [].reduce.call(checkboxes, function(filters, el) {
    if (el.checked) return filters.concat(el.value);
    return filters;
  }, ['vazio']);

  for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var option = options[i];
    option.style.display = filtros.includes(option.getAttribute('data-group')) ? 'block' : 'none';
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="produto"/>Produto</label><br/>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="servico"/>Servicos</label><br/>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="outros"/>Outros</label><br/>
</div>

<select name="listaPSO" id="LISTAPSO">
  <option data-group="vazio" value="">--- Select ---</option>
  <option data-group="produto" value="celular">Celular</option>
  <option data-group="produto" value="tablet">Tablet</option>
  <option data-group="produto" value="tv">TV</option>
  <option data-group="servico" value="troca">Troca</option>
  <option data-group="servico" value="compra">Compra</option>
  <option data-group="outros" value="outros a">Outros A</option>
  <option data-group="outros" value="outros b">Outros B</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks Sergio, your solution works just fine!

Comment: @bernlt ótimo! Se quiseres podes marcar  resposta como aceite